Powershell : Replace text in word with wildcard
I have a powershell script that replace words in MS Word files :
$WordFiles = Get-ChildItem -Recurse | ? Name -like "*.do[c,t]*"

$word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$word.Visible = $false

$MatchCase = $false
$MatchWholeWorld = $true
$MatchWildcards = $false
$MatchSoundsLike = $false
$MatchAllWordForms = $false
$Forward = $false
$Wrap = 1
$Format = $false
$Replace = 2

foreach($WordFile in $WordFiles) {
    $Document = $Word.Documents.Open($WordFile.FullName)

    $Document.Content.Find.Execute("Version : $fromRelease", $MatchCase, $MatchWholeWorld, $MatchWildcards, $MatchSoundsLike, $MatchAllWordForms, $Forward, $Wrap, $Format, "Version : $toRelease", $Replace)

}

But when i try to these wild cards, it doesnt find anything :
$Document.Content.Find.Execute("Microsoft Edge for Business, Version * (64 bits)", $MatchCase, $MatchWholeWord, $true, $MatchSoundsLike, $MatchAllWordForms, $Forward, $Wrap, $Format, "Microsoft Edge for Business, Version 128.0.2739.67 (64 bits)", $Replace)

$Document.Content.Find.Execute("Test N° : ([0-9])", $MatchCase, $MatchWholeWord, $true, $MatchSoundsLike, $MatchAllWordForms, $Forward, $Wrap, $Format, "Test N° : 1", $Replace)

Am i using the wildcard properly ?
Edit : I corrected the first wildcard as pointed, it still did not work. I changed it to avoid * : Microsoft Edge for Business, Version [0-9]{1;4}.[0-9]{1;3}.[0-9]{1;4}.[0-9]{1;4} [(]64 bits[)] Now i have an error : expression is too complex. Finaly Microsoft Edge for Business, Version [0-9]{1;4}.[0-9]{1;3}.[0-9]{1;4}.[0-9]{1;4} is working.

Then shouldn't you set $MatchWildcards = $true if you want to use wildcards ?

@Theo they're passing $true in the second block of examples.

Did you first verify that searching for [0-9] works in Word? Like, manually, when you launch the app and go to perform find-and-replace, does [0-9] actually match any digits?

@Mathias R. Jessen Ah... Completely missed that.

At the very least...If you're searching without wildcards, you can't use "" . If you're searching with wildcards, then () enclose an expression, i.e." (64 bits)" Would find 1.2.3 64 bits, but not 1.2.3 (64 bits), for which you would need the find string "* [(]64 bits[)]".

I assumed that wildcard worked as in word, based on those described here : https://www.gmayor.com/replace_using_wildcards.htm
